# Micronaut Bean Initialization order

Tags: micronaut

I am working on a java application using micronaut framework. I want to make sure all my caches are loaded first (and hence using @Context and @PostConstruct) for all my caches.

After all my caches are loaded I want to load a specific bean ,BeanB (ensuring its @PostConstruct is called in the end).

I tried using @Requires for BeanB (beans={cache1,cache2} etc. but BeanB @PostConstruct gets called before all Caches are done with their @PostConstruct.

Comment: I am not totally clear on what the issue is but if you have a bean that depends on your cache beans and you inject the cache bean into the bean that depends on it, the cache bean will definitely be ready before the bean that depends on it tries to use it, right?

Comment: yes, that works but I would like to keep it separate. Is there something like Spring @Depends(which can have a list of bean name. This way I wont have compile time dependency on my caches and the parent bean

Comment: What interacts with the cache beans?

Comment: my BeanB is actually a finagleServer which i want to start in the end(only after my caches are loaded) . <br/> class BeaB { @PostConstruct public void start(){ ... startFinagleServer }.. <br/> I dont want to inject any cache dependencies in this class as all it is doing is listening to requests. The RequestProcessors for finagle server is actually making use of cache beans

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [BeanInitializedEventListener](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#events)

here is an example of how I understood your usecase:

```
package com.micronaut.example

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanInitializedEventListener
import io.micronaut.context.event.BeanInitializingEvent
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct
import javax.inject.Singleton

class Cache {
    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cache::class.java)
    }

    fun initialized() {
        log.info("initialize")
    }
}

class Server(private val cache1: Cache, private val cache2: Cache) {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Server::class.java)
    }


    fun start() {
        log.info("start")
        cache1.initialized()
        cache2.initialized()
    }
}

@Factory
class ServerFactory {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerFactory::class.java)
    }

    internal lateinit var cache1: Cache
    internal lateinit var cache2: Cache

    private lateinit var server: Server


    @PostConstruct
    fun initialize() {
        log.info("initialize")
        server = Server(cache1, cache2)
        server.start()
    }

    @Singleton
    fun server(): Server {
        return server
    }

}

@Singleton
class CacheInitializer() : BeanInitializedEventListener<ServerFactory> {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheInitializer::class.java)
    }

    init {
        log.info("constructor")
    }

    override fun onInitialized(event: BeanInitializingEvent<ServerFactory>): ServerFactory {
        log.info("onInitialized")
        event.bean.cache1 = Cache()
        event.bean.cache2 = Cache()
        return event.bean
    }

}
```

to test it:

```
package com.micronaut.example

import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class AppTest {

    @Inject
    private lateinit var first: Server

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

this gives you a log output of:

```
INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [test]
INFO  c.micronaut.example.CacheInitializer - constructor
INFO  c.micronaut.example.CacheInitializer - onInitialized
INFO  com.micronaut.example.ServerFactory - initialize
INFO  com.micronaut.example.Server - start
INFO  com.micronaut.example.Cache - initialize
INFO  com.micronaut.example.Cache - initialize
```

I hope the logs are enough information what happens, however basically the `BeanInitializedEventListener` gets calles once the `ServerFactory` was instanciated, but before anything else. Here you can set some params. This ensures that your cache was created before your Server